# How do I create a field on the account object that returns the opportunity with the earliest close date

Tags: lookup-filter, dependent-lookup

As an added bonus, how if I want to do that with child accounts. So it’s the earliest opportunity close date of all the children. Finally, can it be recursive?

It would be a shame if the answer were recursive apex and triggers on the object field.

Comment: My specific question was answered with the vocabulary "roll up summary field" which people with no experience in Salesforce wouldn't just stumble upon and google.  I've seen Group sets in django, or aggregate functions is sql. But it doesn't bother me that this is closed, I got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either Triggers or Process Builder/Flow. Either way, it's going to be more complicated than a simple Rollup Summary Field. That said, the trigger route is easy: just use Andrew Fawcett's excellent [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). As a Process Builder/Flow, you'd have one on the opportunity to update its Account with the earliest value for that account, and for the Account, another Process Builder to roll up those dates to the parents. Not terribly complicated, honestly, but it will take probably 30-60 minutes to build it all out correctly.